How do i integrate the steps of my progress tracker with RPA bots
I need a little help I have an UI , front end : HTML,CSS,JS and backend existing in Flask+Python.
How do I link the steps of a progress tracker i.e UI  to the results from UIPath RPA bot, please help!
I tried using One Drive for real-time updates, but am facing issues
